# How do I build Angular 2 for production using Systemjs?

Tags: angular, systemjs, production

Reading the various sites for building your Angular 2 project for production, there is a tool named Systemjs builder, but it doesn't seem to be a helpful, new developer friendly resource about where to start.  How do I go about building my code minified for production?  Also, will this stop the many, many node_module files from being loaded to the webpage?  Our application takes about 30 seconds to load (if not loading from the cache, where it will take around 7 seconds.  But we want to have a good first impression of our page to a new user, and waiting 30 seconds isn't a great first step!).  Any information would be greatly appreciated!

As I've had a vote to close for being unclear, I'll specify what I am asking.  I'm looking at how to build your code for production using Systemjs builder.  I've looked at online tutorials to configure your build, but these guides don't even indicate whether to add these lines to the Systemjs-config file, or create a new file instead.

Answer (score 1):

Is using the Angular CLI an option for you? It provides built-in features to build your app for production.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki

Comment: Thanks!  I'll take a look into it :)